# How does feedback in power supply work considering output change delay?

Tags: power-supply, feedback

I'm designing an SMPS with a PIC microcontroller, but this question applies not only for SMPS but to linear power supply too.

I set a desired output voltage in my microntroller and then I perform some simple calculations to set an estimated duty cycle that will give me the desired voltage. But this is not exact and output voltage can change when load is applied so I perform and ADC read every 200uS to detect if the output voltage is the voltage I want.

The problem is: let's suppose I want an output voltage of 32V but my current output is 30V so to correct this I start increasing duty cycle and at the same time measuring with the ADC, but, If I increase the duty cycle, the output voltage won't rise automatically, it will take some time due to output capacitance, so, when I perform a new ADC reading the output voltage is still low and I will increase the duty cycle AGAIN because I think my output voltage is still incorrect, but the fact is, it is increasing slowly. At the end I will detect an output voltage above 32V due to the over-increased duty and will start decreasing the duty cycle and the same will happen, so I will have an output oscillating between a maximum and a minimum constantly.

I know I could for example, change duty, wait 20mS and now read the output voltage to give some time to voltage to rise, but this will decrease power supply performance in a transitory. So, how is this problem solved?

This way of thinking makes me guess that linear power supplies like LM723 or any other should face the same problem, am I right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's a control theory problem. SMPSs have it a bit worse because there is a dead time, not just lags.

Comment: Congratulations, you've inadvertently stumbled upon the entire field of control theory :). Google for "PID loops" and you'll find a world of theory solving the exact problem you're describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where control systems come in to play.  I would recommend one of the most common control systems: a PID controller.  Actually, you probably only need a PI controller.  PID stands for Proportional Integral Derivative.  The idea is to adjust the 'control input' (in your case, duty cycle) based on some function of the 'error' (in your case, the difference between the desired voltage and the measured voltage).  The proportional component adjusts the control input based directly on the error (say, duty cycle = 10 * error voltage).  The integral component adjusts the control input based on the integral of the error (for example, duty cycle = 0.1 * running sum of error voltage).  The derivative component adjusts the control input based on the derivative of the error (say, duty cycle = 5 * difference between current measurement and last measurement).  It is quite simple to implement a PID algorithm in software.

The proportional component does most of the work, but it means that there will always be some 'error' required to get the desired control input.  This is where the integral component steps in: the gain builds up over long periods of time, eliminating offsets on long time scales.  The derivative term mostly helps with the step response (overshoot, ringing, response time, etc.).

The building blocks required to construct a PID loop (gain/attenuation blocks/amplifiers, summers, differentiators, integrators) can all be built out of analog circuits (e.g. op amps) so it is possible to construct a purely analog PID loop.  I actually designed a board a while back with a simple analog feedback loop for a thermoelectric cooler controller.  The PID loop itself consisted of a single op amp with a number of resistors and capacitors.  A DAC chip provided the set point that was compared with the voltage across a thermistor.  The same can be done with a power supply, though you generally want much shorter time constants.

Comment: Depending on how accurate or inaccurate he needs it, couldn't he just use the uC to perform the PI or PID control? Especially if he has more expertise in the digital domain, I would think going the digital route would be easier.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a micro.  I was just saying that it's possible to do with analog circuitry as well.  Perhaps I should add that.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying not to use PID because I was having a hard time understanding it! I will have to seat and read through it